# $2f'_n(x)+f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(x)-2/x$ with $f_n(x)= p_n(x)-q_n(x)\text{e}^{-x/2} \text{Ei}(x/2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, polynomials, recurrence-relations

I need to find the closed-form expression of $f_n(x)$ that satisfies the following integral recurrence:

$$f_n(x)=\int_0^\infty f_{n-1}\left(x-a\right)  \, \dfrac{1}{2}  \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a}{2}} da -2\operatorname{Ei}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{2}}$$

with $f_0(x)=0$, where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Exponential_integral&action=edit&section=1), defined as

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^t}t$$

with $\operatorname{Ei}'(x) = \frac{e^x}x$.

What I know is that the function $f_n(x)$ has the following form:

$$f_n(x)= \left [a(n)_0+a(n)_2x+\dots a(n)_{n-2}x^{n-2}\right] -\left [b(n)_0+b(n)_2x+\dots b(n)_{n-1}x^{n-1}\right]\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{2}}\operatorname{Ei}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right).$$

Also, from the above integral recurrence I derived the following recurrence:

$$\fbox{$2f'_n(x)+f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(x)-2/x$},$$

which can be used to **find recurrences among the polynomial coefficients**.

Could you find the **closed-form expressions** of the vectors: $$a(n)=\left(a(n)_0,\dots, a(n)_{n-2} \right)\in \mathbb R^{n-1} \\ b(n)=\left (b(n)_0,\dots, b(n)_{n-1} \right ) \in \mathbb R^{n}$$ appearing in the above two polynomials of degrees $n-2$ and $n-1$ based on the above recurrence?

The vectors for $n=1, 2, 3, 4$ are as follows:

$a(1)= - \,, \quad b(1)=(2) \\
a(2)=(2), \quad b(2)=(2, 1) \\
a(3)=(3,\frac{1}{2}), \quad b(3)=(2,1, \frac{1}{4}) \\
a(4)=(\frac{11}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{12}), \quad b(4)=(2,1, \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{24}).$

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail for why $f_{n}(x)$ takes the form you say it does?

Comment: @AidanR.S. A short answer is that it is obtained in the process of computing a somehow complex expected value of a random variable that can be written as the sum of $n$ independent exponentially distributed random variables.

Comment: @AidanR.S. I uncovered the form by comparing the expressions of the function $f_n$ for small values of $n$.

Comment: In fact you must have $2f'_n(x)+f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(x)-\color{red}{4}/x$.